# Subset of $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, ideals

I have a past exam question that is as follows:

> Let $k$ be a fixed integer and $S = \{(a,ka)|a \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ be a subset of $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$. Prove that $S$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ under addition. For which value(s) of $k$ is $S$ a subring of $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$? For which value(s) of $k$ is $S$ an ideal of $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$? Justify your answers.

$S$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ under addition:

Proof

Associativity: $(a,ka)+((b,kb)+(c,kc)) = (a,ka) + (b+c,kb+kc) = (a+b+c,k(a+b+c))$

$((a,ka)+(b,kb))+(c,kc)=(a+b,ka+kb)+(c,kc)=(a+b+c,k(a+b+c))$

Inverse: $(a,ka) + (-a,-ka) = (0,0)$

Identity: $(a,ka) + (0,0) = (a,ka)$

Hence $S$ is a subgroup

For $k = 0,1$ $S$ is a subring:

Proof

$Let \; k = 0,(a,0)(b,0)=(ab,0), \; let \; ab=c, (ab,0) = (c,kc)=(c,0)$
$(a,0)+(b,0)= (a+b,0), \; let \; a+b=c, (c,0) = (c,kc)$

$Let \; k = 1,(a,a)(b,b)=(ab,ab)=(c,kc)=(c,c) $
$(a,a)+(b,b) = (a+b,a+b), \; let \; a+b=c, (c,kc)=(c,c)$
Hence $S$ holds  additive and multiplicity closure, and is therefore a subring.

$S$ is only an ideal of $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ at $k=0$
$(s,ks)(b,c)=(b,c)(s,ks)=(sb,ksc)=(sb,0sc)=(sb,0)=(a,o)$, which can't have form $(a,ka)$ with the second term equalling anything other than zero. Not sure if this is a proper solution.

Comment: Note that $k$ is fixed. So it should be $(a, ka) + (b, kb)$.

Comment: I suggest that you show some works so that we know how we can offer our help.

Comment: @John Oh yes, that is a good call, I did actually consider that, but for some reason I didn't go at it that way.

Well I have shown associativity and communitivity, and inverse is $-a$, $(a,ka) + (-a,-ka) = (0,0)$, identity is $0$, $(a,ka)+(0,0k) = (a,ka)$

I will edit in attempt to the next two parts soon.

Comment: @Exam: You did this on the last question too so I'll mention it: don't tag these posts "homological algebra". Admittedly, the tag doesn't do a great job convincing you that this is not homological algebra, but it isn't :)

Comment: For the subring case, what about other values of $k$?

Comment: @EricStucky It would seem only values of $k$ that satisfy $k^2 = k$ work to make $S$ a subring. Which I am fairly sure(unless I am missing something obvious) only has integer solutions $k=0,1$? $(a,ka)(b,kb)=(ab,abk^2)=(c,k^2 \cdot c)$

Comment: Yes, that is the right line of argument.

Comment: A more conceptual way of showing that $S$ is a subgroup would be to observe that it is the image of the map $f: \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ defined by $f(a) = (a,ka)$. It is clear that $f$ is a group homomorphism with respect to addition. In case $k=0$ or $1$, $f$ is moreover a ring homomorphism; thus its image $S$ is a subring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some authors it is required that a ring contains a multiplicative identity element. I'm not sure if that's the case for you, but my guess would be no, since you seem to imply that ideals are subrings. [Exercise: Any ideal containing the identity element is the entire ring.]

If not, then yes: you need only show multiplicative closure. The distributive law follows from the fact that you are already inside an ambient ring.

Formally,

> A subset $I$ is an *ideal* of a ring $R$ if is a (additive) subgroup of $R$ with the following property: For every $i\in I$, and every $r\in R$, then both $ri\in I$ and $ir\in I$.

Note that this is a strictly stronger condition than multiplicative closure. This is because $r$ is allowed to be *any* element in $R$, even elements which are not in the ideal $I$. Talking about an "ideal ring", therefore, is discouraged, since every ring is an ideal in itself. But it becomes a meaningful (and rather strong) condition when considering subrings of an ambient ring.

Comment: I feel bad about telling you to do something I haven't done myself, but it might be instructive to find a subring which is not an ideal. I can at least tell you this: it is not possible to do this in $\mathbb Z$: I know that because we know all subgroups of $\mathbb Z$, and you can check fairly easily that all of them are ideals.

Comment: With finding which values of $k$ make $S$ an ideal of $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$, am I looking at $(s,ks)(a,a)$ or $(s,ks)(a,b)$ where $(a,a),(a,b)\in\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ $(s,ks)\in S$ (if that makes sense)

I assume the second, which has only solution $k=0$ I suppose.

Comment: Yes, you want a generic element in $\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z$, so $(a,b)$ is appropriate.

Comment: Is my ideal idea right? $k=0$

Comment: @Exam: It's a little poorly written, but the idea is there. A good writeup would not introduce $k=0$ until after the generic calculation, and then explain what happens in the $k=0$ and $k\neq 0$ cases separately.